# How to convert 2 float value into 2.00 in the output using bigsql?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigsql

I would like to convert float value 2.0 into 2.00 in the output. How can i achieve the same in bigquery?

e.g. I have value 6412.7 as an input. I would like to have output like 6412.70.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything called BigSQL in GCP, in addition SO is not a free consultant/coding service. Show what you've tried or investigated.

Comment: Please improve your questions following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST(1200.555 AS STRING FORMAT '999,999.99') as a;